# Filter and extract from HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

From the following code (simplified code):

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">1000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">4300</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to extract the following information for everyone on GROUP1:

```
NAME1 Score:1000
NAME3 Score:3000
```

And write it on, if possible, a .txt.
If writing into a txt is not possible on javascript, console.log is fine too.

Comment: In what environment? A browser? NodeJS? The JVM? A Windows metro app?

Comment: Assuming you are targeting the browser, are you using/can you use jQuery?

Comment: In a browser, im using Javascript without plugins

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service. You are expected to show your attempts to solve your own issues yourself. Then people help you with **your code** that isn't working as expected

Comment: @DHONJOE Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct an object that contains every group. Then you need to filter it. You can do something like this:

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
var myObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
  // Get the group.
  group = trs[i].querySelector(".groupLink").innerHTML.trim();
  myObj[group] = myObj[group] || [];
  myObj[group].push({
    "name": trs[i].querySelector(".name a").innerHTML.trim(),
    "score": trs[i].querySelector(".score").innerHTML.trim()
  });
}
console.log(myObj["GROUP1"]);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">1000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">4300</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get the output here:

```
[
  {
    "name": "NAME1",
    "score": "1000"
  },
  {
    "name": "NAME3",
    "score": "3000"
  }
]
```

You can use a simple loop to format your output:

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
var myObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
  // Get the group.
  group = trs[i].querySelector(".groupLink").innerHTML.trim();
  myObj[group] = myObj[group] || [];
  myObj[group].push({
    "name": trs[i].querySelector(".name a").innerHTML.trim(),
    "score": trs[i].querySelector(".score").innerHTML.trim()
  });
}
for (var j = 0; j < myObj["GROUP1"].length; j++)
  console.log(myObj["GROUP1"][j].name + " Score: " + myObj["GROUP1"][j].score);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">1000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">4300</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Output**

```
NAME1 Score: 1000
NAME3 Score: 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's just a matter of iterating over the cells and extracting the relevant information.

You could do that like this:

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
rows.forEach(function(el){
  const name = el.querySelector(".name a").innerHTML.trim();
  const score = el.querySelector(".score").innerHTML.trim();
  console.log(`${name} Score:${score}`);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" href="" onclick="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" href="" onclick="">GROUP2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">4300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" onclick="">NAME3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a class="groupLink" href="" onclick="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to extract the following information for everyone on GROUP1

Short solution using single loop with `Array.prototype.forEach()` function:

```js
var result = [];
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr.alt')).forEach(function(el){
    var childs = el.children;
    if (childs[1].children[0].innerHTML === 'GROUP1') {
        this.push({Name: childs[0].children[0].innerHTML.trim(), Score: childs[2].innerHTML.trim()})
    }
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table><tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
         <a href="" onclick="">NAME1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
         <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">1000</td>
</tr>

<tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
        <a href="" onclick="">NAME2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
        <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">4300</td>
</tr>

<tr class="alt">
    <td class="name">
        <a href="" onclick="">NAME3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
         <a class="groupLink" onclick="" href="">GROUP1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="score">3000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```